# OpenNETCF.Net.Ftp Behaving Flaky

Tags: compact-framework, ftp

I tried posting on their boards (authors of this library), however it literally takes months for them to reply when it comes to the free software (can't blame them).

But anyways
I have found that this library is behaving weirdly - for instance, a major problem with my application is when someone is trying to sign in (through FTP), they provide a correct login and mistype the password, no reply is received from FTP server.

I tried doing the same from command window just to verify that it's not the FTP server's fault; and FTP commands were received instantaneously.

It almost looks as though this library eats the commands. The same actions often times will yield different results.

Can anyone recommend a stable, reliable library to use with Compact framework? Or shed some light on this issue...?

Answer (score 1):

I modified the source code inside ConnectThread() as follows:

```
// if a PWD is required, send it
            if( response.ID == 331 )
            {

                response = SendCommand("PASS " + m_pwd, false);

                //ADDED THIS - try again.
                if (response.ID == 0)
                {
                    response = SendCommand("PASS " + m_pwd, false);
                }
                //end of my addition

                if( !((response.ID == 202) || (response.ID == 230)) )
                {
                    m_cmdsocket.Close();
                    m_cmdsocket=null;
                    Disconnect();
                    m_connected = false;
                    return;
                    }
}
```

This solved the issue for awhile, until now it started doing it again, the culprit seems to be when 0 is coming back as a response from FTP server, the connection just stalls. I am not sure whether it is a socket issue or some other obscure problem, but I think I am going to give up at this point.

Comment: I'm going to move that library over to Codeplex so it will be easier to maintain and accept patches.

Comment: Actually, it still doesn't work, it just did it again. so I spoke too soon. Do you have any idea on why 0 is received as a response from the FTP server?

Answer (score 0):

Which FTP set are you using, the stream-based classes in the SDF, or the [separate one in the Forums](http://community.opennetcf.com/forums/t/10502.aspx)?  If you're using the one from the forums (which is the one I actually recommend), then you've got the source.  I wrote that one from the ground up by looking at nothing by the RFC.  It's really, really simple and if it's "eating" responses, it's likely a timeout issue, though it should be easy to put in a break point and see where it's coming apart.

Comment: Hi Chris, yes I am using the one in the forums (so I can look in the source code). I actually put a debug output statement inside  ReadResponse() function and surely enough, when a user types in their account number and wrong password, all I get from the FTP server is 220 and then 331 codes. Afterwords, it just stalls. However, it doesn't always happen, but it happens often enough for the users to complain. I would rather not modify the source code at all as it will require for me to go through it and understand it and I don't have time allocated for this.

Comment: which time-out are you talking about? the server time out or the connection time out? I am assuming it's the connection time out.

Comment: So, here is where it eats the response(inside ConnectThread)

   if( response.ID == 331 )
   {
                MessageBox.Show("sending p/w");

                response = SendCommand("PASS " + m_pwd, false);

                MessageBox.Show("end: response id: " + response.ID.ToString());
                
    if( !((response.ID == 202) || (response.ID == 230)) )
                {
                    m_cmdsocket.Close();
     m_cmdsocket=null;
                    Disconnect();
     m_connected = false;
     return;
                }
                
   }

after p/w is sent, I get 0 as response.

Comment: ok, this is officially driving me INSANE. (sorry for caps).
now it's working all of a sudden. What the?
also, I have a question for you: how come CommandSent is never raised even though the login is successful (in the case where login and password are correct)

CommandSent != null is ALWAYS false. Is that normal???